# web request from the user browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, browser

is it possible to send a web request from the user browser to another api and then process the result sent back??

im trying the following ajax code but its not working, i was wondering whether is it possible or not and if its a yes how can i implement it ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=a9a2b0ec2c4724dd95286761777b09f1c8e82894de277a5b9d7175fa5275f2da&ip=&output=xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                alert("sucess");
                $(xml).find('Ip').each(function() {
                    var ip = $(this).find('Ip').text();
                    alert(ip);

                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you are pretty limited to sending AJAX requests to your own domain only. [JSONP](http://insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html) is a common workaround but the remote site needs to support it. Another workaround consists in crating a server side script on your domain which will serve as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain and it will simply delegate the AJAX request sent to it from javascript.

Comment: actually if u examine the url u'll notice that the ip=  is empty and when a request is made with ip=null it returns a xml which contains the ip of the user if i send the request from my server how will i get the ip of the user ...

Comment: @3nigma: If you send the request from your server then just have your server get the IP address of the client and put it into the url. I assume this will do what you want.

Comment: @3nigma: Its probably most sensible to ask that as a new question rather than tryign to deal with it here in comments. You're also likely to get a lot more and better help on it.

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible, I have done the same.

BUT you have to have the pages on the same server, you cannot send a request to another server, in that case you would have to use a proxy on your server to relay the call.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what was already said: if you can't create your own JSONP proxy, you can use [YQL service](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) which creates that proxy for you. Note that YQL will wrap your data with it's own meta data (unless there is a way yo disable that...).

By the way, you should use JSON output instead of XML output from your API service. JSON is a more lightweight format and as such is more adapted for Web.

Below is a fully functional example with your API URL (outputting JSON this time) and YQL:

```
var apiRequestUrl = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=a9a2b0ec2c4724dd95286761777b09f1c8e82894de277a5b9d7175fa5275f2da&ip=&output=json";
var yqlRequestUrl = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22";
yqlRequestUrl += encodeURIComponent(apiRequestUrl);
yqlRequestUrl += "%22&format=json&callback=?";

$.getJSON(yqlRequestUrl,
    function(jsonData) {
        alert(jsonData.query.results.json.Ip);
    });
```

Finally, this article can come handy: http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

Comment: tnx for the help but this way i get the ip of the proxy from which the request is sent not the ip of the client...